# cov_type='HAC' error statsmodels 0.7 IPython 3 notebook python 2.7 anaconda mac os x

Tags: python, ipython, regression, statsmodels

i was trying fit OLS model, thats works correctly without robust estimation, but i want improve my regression so, like below, i try to implement that with this problem, in comments have other attempts to solve it.

I don't know if a apply correctly the keyword, so I apresure any helps.

## Code:

```
# Fit and summarize OLS model
sumrz = dict()

for i, ca in enumerate(ccaa):
    x = sm.add_constant(data.dy[ca])
    mod = sm.OLS(endog=data.du[ca], exog=x, hasconst=True, missing='drop')
    res = mod.fit(cov_type='HAC', cov_kwds={'maxlags':1})
#    res = res.get_robustcov_results(cov_type='HAC', maxlags=1, use_correction=True)
#    res = res.get_robustcov_results(cov_type='HC0')
    sumrz[ca] = res.summary(xname=['const','dy'], yname='du', title=ca)
```

## Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-87912e59a35d> in <module>()
      9 #    res = res.get_robustcov_results(cov_type='HAC', maxlags=1, use_correction=True)
     10 #    res = res.get_robustcov_results(cov_type='HC0')
---> 11     sumrz[ca] = res.summary(xname=['const','dy'], yname='du', title=ca)

/Users/mmngreco/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.pyc in summary(self, yname, xname, title, alpha)
   1950         top_right = [('R-squared:', ["%#8.3f" % self.rsquared]),
   1951                      ('Adj. R-squared:', ["%#8.3f" % self.rsquared_adj]),
-> 1952                      ('F-statistic:', ["%#8.4g" % self.fvalue] ),
   1953                      ('Prob (F-statistic):', ["%#6.3g" % self.f_pvalue]),
   1954                      ('Log-Likelihood:', None), #["%#6.4g" % self.llf]),

/Users/mmngreco/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/decorators.pyc in __get__(self, obj, type)
     92         if _cachedval is None:
     93             # Call the "fget" function
---> 94             _cachedval = self.fget(obj)
     95             # Set the attribute in obj
     96 #            print("Setting %s in cache to %s" % (name, _cachedval))

/Users/mmngreco/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.pyc in fvalue(self)
   1214                 # assume const_idx exists
   1215                 idx = lrange(k_params)
-> 1216                 idx.pop(const_idx)
   1217                 mat = mat[idx]  # remove constant
   1218             ft = self.f_test(mat)

TypeError: an integer is required
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(It's good to see a full traceback in a question.)

The following is my guess based on the traceback.

I guess there is a bug in the constant detection if `hasconst=True` is specifiec.
Try to leave out the argument `hasconst=True`.

**Background**

If we don't allow for misspecified heteroscedasticity or correlation, and we don't use a robust covariance matrix, then the F statistic can be calculated from the residual sum of squares.

If a robust `cov_type` is specified, then we use the Wald test for the null hypothesis that all slope coefficients are zero. This is valid with a robust covariance of the parameters even if heteroscedasticity or correlation are misspecified.

In this case the index for the column with the constant, `const_idx`, is not correctly set and we get the TypeError.

Comment: (Thanks for that)

I leave out the argument `hasconst=True` like you suggest and works well now. So Thanks!!

Comment: As reference:I opened https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2581 to keep track of this, and fix it.